# How to get specific column data from SQLite table and pass it to an ArrayList? code included

Tags: java, android, arraylist

Here is the method to get one column from the table.

```
 public ArrayList<String> getStatusValues (){
   SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
   ArrayList<String> statusList = new ArrayList<>();
   // String query = CHECKLIST_TABLE, new String[]{}
   Cursor cursor = db.query(CHECKLIST_TABLE, new String[]{CHECKLIST_STATUS},
           CHECKLIST_STATUS + " =? ", new String[]{(CHECKLIST_STATUS)}, null, null, null);
   if(cursor.moveToFirst()){
       do {
          String status =  cursor.getString(1);
           statusList.add(status);
       }
       while (cursor.moveToNext());
   }
    return statusList;
}
```

The code to get status ArrayList in MainActivity, but get nothing in logical.

```
DbHelper dbHelper = new DbHelper(this);
    ArrayList<String> statusList = dbHelper.getStatusValues();

    for(int i = 0; i < statusList.size(); i++) {
        Log.d("gon", "status -> " + statusList.get(i));
    }
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The arguments to `#query` are a little suspect. What is the value of `CHECKLIST_STATUS`, and the column name associated with it?

Comment: Column name is CHECKLIST_STATUS and the values are numbers which are inserted. In each cell of of the CHECKLIST_STATUS the numbers which are inserted using StrinBuilder. Insertion process works fine, no problem in it, but the problem is getting values again to an ArrayList. For example in the index [0] of CHECKLIST_STATUS the numbers either 0 or 1. Later I use these numbers to assign CheckBoxes values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem fixed by removing `CHECKLIST_STATUS + " =? ", new String[]{(CHECKLIST_STATUS)},`

and adding null, null instead of that and also made the CHECKLIST_STATUS field public.